# how to know if code coming from local cache vs server

Tags: fiddler

In fiddler, is there any way of knowing if some piece of code ( jscript, jquery, css) are been loaded from local cache vs downloaded from the server. I think this may be represented by different color in web sessions, but wasn't able to find legend for these colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see `304 Not Modified` responses, those mean that the client made a conditional request, and server is signalling "no need to download, you have the newest version cached". That's one "class" of cached responses.

However, for some entities, not even conditional requests are sent (`Expires` header is in the future, etc. - see [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) ). Those would not show up in Fiddler at all, as there is no request at all - the client may assume that the cached version is fresh.

What you *can* certainly see are the non-cached resources - anything coming back with a response code from the `2xx` range should be non-cached (unless there's a seriously misconfigured caching proxy upstream, but those are rare nowadays).

You could clear your caches, and open the page. Save those results. Then open the page again - see what's missing when compared to the first load; those are cached.

Comment: Where should I look for these 304s? There are some contents that I think are in cache but when I see in Result column under WebSessions they are proted as 200. What am I missing?

Comment: The same column where the 200s normally appear. 200 is "OK" - not cached. 304 is "Not Modified" - checked for freshness, and then used from cache. If you see all 200s, then those aren't cached; but there may be additional objects that aren't checked at all and fetched directly from cache.

Answer (score 2):

Fiddler is an HTTP proxy, so it does not show cached content at all.

Comment: It does show `304 Not Modified` responses, though - those indicate "you already have this, serve it from local cache". But you're correct that non-expired entities don't have to be even requested conditionally.

Comment: OK, is there any tool that can be used to figure out which web contents (images, scripts etc) are used from cahce vs from server. I heard firebug can be used for it but not sure if IE version has it available. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also where does it show 304? Is it the result column under WebSessions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936284/browser-caching-why-does-ie9-always-show-http-304-when-actually-it-did-not-hit for discussion of the IE9 Network tab and the bug it has around cache vs. 304.